# How to set the "Order" of Items in a hierarchy table?

Tags: t-sql, cursor, common-table-expression

The result of a CTE is stored in a variable table name @tbl.

I want to set the Order (SO) of MenuItems by MenuItemID, ParentID (PID) and MenuID. To do so I tried to use a Cursor, but it's too complicated for me to figure it out.

**EDIT:**
 In fact the SO (Order) of the sample data are not **in order** as they should be continuously. I want to Re-Set their order as in hierarchy and the current SO:

Current SO (not continuous):

```
1   5   2   9   10  6   7
```

Corrected:

```
1   2   1   2   3   3   4

> 1
> 2
    > 1
    > 2
    > 3
> 3
> 4
```

@tbl Contents:

```
MenuItemID                              ParentID                                MenuID                                  SO   Level
D3B92D1B-7AFA-4E11-AF01-9F6A00B1B2A9    C0489C0C-18C7-4D9A-8FC2-A19A00CDB99E    C0489C0C-18C7-4D9A-8FC2-A19A00CDB99E    1    0
F5833F72-A739-47D6-B30C-A19600F03E91    C0489C0C-18C7-4D9A-8FC2-A19A00CDB99E    C0489C0C-18C7-4D9A-8FC2-A19A00CDB99E    5    0
5C2AC1F8-DEE0-448B-B538-A19600F0839B    C0489C0C-18C7-4D9A-8FC2-A19A00CDB99E    C0489C0C-18C7-4D9A-8FC2-A19A00CDB99E    6    0
3A1096E7-5FD2-4F77-9729-A19600973BDF    C0489C0C-18C7-4D9A-8FC2-A19A00CDB99E    C0489C0C-18C7-4D9A-8FC2-A19A00CDB99E    7    0
EBB5FFF0-4407-436B-BCE8-A1A0010A1A88    F5833F72-A739-47D6-B30C-A19600F03E91    C0489C0C-18C7-4D9A-8FC2-A19A00CDB99E    2    1
45077C15-3A47-43E2-92A1-A19C013C2D9C    F5833F72-A739-47D6-B30C-A19600F03E91    C0489C0C-18C7-4D9A-8FC2-A19A00CDB99E    9    1
9DDB77B9-C9E8-48AF-8F1E-A1960097329A    F5833F72-A739-47D6-B30C-A19600F03E91    C0489C0C-18C7-4D9A-8FC2-A19A00CDB99E    10   1
```

And the result I want would be something like this:

(The MenuItems should be ordered by Level, SO (Sort Order))

```
MenuItemID                              ParentID                                MenuID                                  SO   Level
D3B92D1B-7AFA-4E11-AF01-9F6A00B1B2A9    C0489C0C-18C7-4D9A-8FC2-A19A00CDB99E    C0489C0C-18C7-4D9A-8FC2-A19A00CDB99E    1    0
F5833F72-A739-47D6-B30C-A19600F03E91    C0489C0C-18C7-4D9A-8FC2-A19A00CDB99E    C0489C0C-18C7-4D9A-8FC2-A19A00CDB99E    2    0
EBB5FFF0-4407-436B-BCE8-A1A0010A1A88    F5833F72-A739-47D6-B30C-A19600F03E91    C0489C0C-18C7-4D9A-8FC2-A19A00CDB99E    1    1
45077C15-3A47-43E2-92A1-A19C013C2D9C    F5833F72-A739-47D6-B30C-A19600F03E91    C0489C0C-18C7-4D9A-8FC2-A19A00CDB99E    2    1
9DDB77B9-C9E8-48AF-8F1E-A1960097329A    F5833F72-A739-47D6-B30C-A19600F03E91    C0489C0C-18C7-4D9A-8FC2-A19A00CDB99E    3    1
5C2AC1F8-DEE0-448B-B538-A19600F0839B    C0489C0C-18C7-4D9A-8FC2-A19A00CDB99E    C0489C0C-18C7-4D9A-8FC2-A19A00CDB99E    3    0
3A1096E7-5FD2-4F77-9729-A19600973BDF    C0489C0C-18C7-4D9A-8FC2-A19A00CDB99E    C0489C0C-18C7-4D9A-8FC2-A19A00CDB99E    4    0
```

And the cursor I was to going to use is like this, but I don't know what to do with it:

```
declare @id uniqueidentifier
declare cur CURSOR LOCAL for
    SELECT MenuItemID FROM @tbl order by lvl
open cur
    fetch next from cur into @id
    while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 BEGIN
        ???
    fetch next from cur into @id
    end
close cur
deallocate cur
```

And here is the table (@tbl) structure:

```
declare @tbl table (MenuItemID uniqueidentifier, PID uniqueidentifier, MenuID uniqueidentifier, SO tinyint, lvl tinyint)
```

I'd highly appreciate if someone help me.

Thanks in advance,

Kardo

Comment: The sort order in the example results doesn't match the order given (Level, SO), nor any other ordering that I can see. Can you clarify what ordering you are trying to achieve? Also, the SO values in the results do not match those in the data - can you clarify whether you want different SO values in the results, and if so how they are to be derived?

Comment: I didn't understand you exactly, but in this example the items with PID = 'F5833F72-A739-47D6-B30C-A19600F03E91', SO = 2 are the children of that item, therefor are sorted as 1, 2, 3

Comment: @MarkBannister, I edited my question. Hope this is more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a recursive CTE, rather than a cursor:

```
with hier as
(select l0.*, convert(varchar(max),right('000'+convert(varchar(3),SO),3)) FullSO 
 from tbl l0 where lvl=0
 union all
 select ln.*, lp.FullSO+','+right('000'+convert(varchar(3),ln.SO),3) FullSO
 from tbl ln
 join hier lp on ln.PID = lp.MenuItemID)
select MenuItemID, 
       PID, 
       MenuID,
       rank() over (partition by PID order by SO) SO,
       lvl
from hier
order by FullSO, SO
```

SQLFiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/af885/17).

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot buddy! I tested my approach and it was not successful in multi-sub categories, but your's is working as expected. Thanks again :)

Comment: hey Mark, would you take a look at my answer (in fact question) please?